# java: Can I sort a String type number with same length

Tags: java, string, sorting

there are strings like '20190709','20190929', etc. Their length are the same and all 'nummber'. I am trying  to sort them without transfering to other type and I hope the result is same as int sorting. We don't talk about effeciency problem. Is there other problem that would make a wrong result?

Comment: That should work without any problems.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks，can you explain it in details?

Comment: that works but the natural order is used, so the string is not treated as  a numeric value. However you could pass an own Comparator to the sort method and there compare Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2)). Of course you can also use method expressions like cameron, but that will break if there is a non-numeric. Own comparator allows you to handle that explicitly

Comment: @wl.GIG Can you explain your question in detail?  Do you think this meets the minimum requirements for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) question with sufficient research done?

Comment: @ItFreak i think natural order is like int sorting order. I am not sure that. Why would they not treat as numeric value?

Comment: @Nexevis sorry I don’t know what MCVE is. I think my real problem is if the result same , when use alphabetical sorting and numeric sorting to handle the string I mentioned.

Comment: This smells like a homework question. The OP's followup questions requesting more detail make it seem like the OP is drip-feeding parts to an assignment.

Comment: @wl.GIG because the string is not converted to an integer. for example, in a lexicographic order, 200 is greater than 1999, because a string comparison results in 2 being greater than 1

Comment: @BenR. it is not a homework question. This problem came from an argue with my colleague. He wants to use a string ranking in MySQL.

Comment: @ItFreak yeah, it is true. But my condition is strings have same size. In this case, they might be same?

Comment: if you can assure that all strings have the same length, this should work. However it is nonsense, since there is an explicit numerical order that can handle inputs of different lengths :D

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort a list of `String`s in numerical order, the easiest way is:

- `Arrays.sort(strings, Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt));` for a `String[]`
- `Collections.sort(strings, Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt));` for a `List<String>`.

You say "without transferring to another type". The above methods will implicitly convert the `String`s to `int`s, but you will still keep your `String` references.

Most methods to sort `String`s will use alphabetical order, which will give a different result to numerical order.

These methods are also relatively efficient.

Comment: thank you for answer，if use alphabetical sorting method in same conditions above, what problem would happen?

Comment: @luk2302 I did try it. I did not find any problem. But I think it should have some problems that I did not find.